# Stratified boostrap for stratified experiment

Tags: bootstrap, stratification

I'm running an AB test where I split customers into A and B by stratifiying on the levels of a variable X. I collect data like this:

```
customer_id,treatment,y,X
1,A,1.1,Low
2,B,1.2,High
3,A,1.1,High
4,B,1.2,Low
```

I want to run a bootstrap to calculate confidence intervals of the difference in medians.

To do the boostrap, in each iteration, I take two samples:

- Randomly sample customers in A with replacement
- Randomly sample customers in B with replacement

And then compute the difference in medians. Should I do this? Or should I sample with stratas? Why or why not?

Comment: Are the two groups of roughly equal size?

Comment: Yes they are, more or less

Comment: Then stratification is likely to be of little value. You will probably use the strata size as weight when resampling, and if they are of equal size it will be similar to random sampling.